# go lang map not throwing null pointer

Tags: go

Why does this program not panic?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    m["test"] = "test"
    delete(m, "tes1t")

    m = nil
    fmt.Println("End")
    fmt.Println(m["test"])
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/37reql6Pdb5

event hough `m` is `nil`, it's still possible to read items in `m`.

Comment: @qrsngky: If you are curious how maps work at runtime, you can see the implementation details here: https://go.dev/src/runtime/map.go You'll notice that while the type in your program is declared as `map[key]val`, in `runtime/map.go`, a hash map is a `struct` type. If you try to read a value from a map, there's an explicit nil check which returns a zero value. This is how the implementation gives you a value without panicking.

Answer (score 6):

Check out this code snippet:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var m map[string]string = nil
    fmt.Println(m) // output: "map[]"

}
```

This is an intended behavior since `nil` acts as zero value for many types of variables, including (but not limited to) *maps* and *slices*.

Also, there's no such thing in Golang as "Exception". You can check if a value exists in your map using this syntax:

```golang
value, found := m["key"]
```

where the `found` variable indicates if the value exists in the map.